# How to trigger a function from function returns an array of component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

//  I have list page , listing results of some data . I have created a function takes data as a parameter and returns rows by that data . I need to trigger onClicked() functions when item pressed.

```
//  I have already tried lots of examples but could not handle it    
// THIS IS MY FUCTION WHICH I WANT TO TRIGGER

onClicked(){
  alert('clicked')
}


//THIS IS MY ALL TABLE CODE 

return(
   <View>
                <OrderListHeaderView/>
                <ScrollView>
                   {ordersRow.rendersRows(this.state.trasmittedOrders)}
                </ScrollView>
   </View>
);

//THIS IS MY FUNCTION RETURNS ROWS

rendersRows(orders) {

        return orders.map((item,index) => {
          return (
            <Swipeable
            key={index}
            rightButtonWidth={100}
            rightButtons={[
               <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={()=>{
                    //I WANT TO TRIGGER ONCLICK FUNCTION

                }}
              >
                     <Icon name='search'>  
               </TouchableOpacity>,     
                    ]}>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.customer.name</Text>
                    </View>
            </Swipeable>
          )
        })

    }
```

I expect to see 'clicked' alert when TouchableOpacity pressed

Comment: What's wrong with `<TouchableOpacity onPress={onClicked} > ...` ? Perhaps I'm missing something, are they in different classes?

Comment: yes, they are in different class @jujunol

Comment: Could you update your code to clarify how the code is laid out?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code looks something like

```
class C1 extends React.Component {
  funcToRun() {
    // code to run on click
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <View>
        <OrderListHeaderView/>
        <ScrollView>
          {ordersRow.rendersRows(this.state.trasmittedOrders)}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class C2 extends React.Component {
  renderRows(orders) {
    orders.map((order, index) => ( 
      ...
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={/* event here */} />
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

In React, typically we would want to solve this issue by `lifting state up` (good example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html))

To this within your example, you'd have to move some things around to make it work

```
class C1 extends React.Component {
  funcToRun() {
    // code to run on click
  }

  renderRows(rows) {
    return rows.map((order, index) => <C2Row onPress={() => this.funcToRun()} />);
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <View>
        <OrderListHeaderView/>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.rendersRows(this.state.trasmittedOrders)}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class C2Row extends React.Component {
  render() {
      ...
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress()} />
      ...
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: YOU ARE LEGEND MAN, THANKS A LOT !! @jujunol